# how to find next directly download cell within a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, html-table

I have a table with colspan rowspan eg.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 id="mytable" > 
  <tr><td>A1</td> <td> A2 </td> <td> A3 </td><td>A4</td><td>A5</td> <td>A6</td> <td>A7</td> <td>A8</td>  </tr>
  <tr><td>B1</td> <td colspan=3 >B2-B4</td>             <td>B5</td> <td>B6</td> <td>B7</td> <td>B8</td> </tr> 
  <tr><td>C1</td> <td> C2 </td> <td colspan=3> C3 -C5</td>          <td>C6</td> <td>C7</td> <td>C8</td></tr>
  <tr><td>D1</td> <td colspan=2 rowspan=2> D2- E3 </td><td>D4</td> <td>D5</td> <td>D6</td> <td>D7</td> <td>D8</td></tr>
  <tr><td>E1</td>                                      <td>E4</td> <td>E5</td> <td>E6</td> <td>E7</td> <td>E8</td></tr>
  <tr><td>F1</td> <td> F2 </td> <td> F3 </td><td>F4</td><td>F5</td> <td>F6</td> <td>F7</td> <td>F8</td>  </tr>
  </table>
```

now I am at some cell
how to get the next directly downside cell.
(this is for ui interaction response on  key down action.)
eg.
If now I am at cell A2 ,I want to get B2-B4,
If now I am at cell A3 ,I want to get B2-B4,
If now I am at cell B2-B4 ,I want to get C2,
If now I am at cell B5 ,I want to get C3-C5,
If now I am at cell A3 ,I want to get B2-B4,
If now I am at cell C3-C5 ,I want to get D2-E3,
If now I am at cell D2-E3 ,I want to get F2,
in javascript code how to get this kind of next cell .

Comment: no ,this is not content processing ,I need to do some UI interaction.
for example when user press down arrow key.I need to focus to the specified cell.

Comment: 'If now I am at cell C3-C5 ,I want to get D2-E3' -> this rowspan make problems... Why not D4 or D5? Why D2-E3 is next cell, in this case?

Comment: Ui: ok, valid point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0knmhLx/1/)

JS Code:

```
var valueStr = 'C2';
var tdObj = $("td:contains('"+valueStr+"')");
var trObj = tdObj.closest('tr');
var tdIndex = trObj.find(tdObj).index();
var reqTD = trObj.next().find('td:eq('+tdIndex+')');
alert(reqTD.html());
```

Comment: actually you use Cell.cellIndex equal to find the next one,it is not enough.
A5 will result to B7 ,that is not as expected.
 B5 is expected.

Answer (score 0):

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucupp15h/3/)**
This is what i tried now, not all your test cases done. still working on it

```
$("#mytable").on('click', 'td', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var dt = self.html();
    $("#aData1").html("You clicked @ block = " + dt);

    var x = self.index();
    var y = self.parent().next().find("td:eq(" + x + ")").html();
    $("#aData2").html("Next block is : " + y);
});
```

Comment: actually you use Cell.cellIndex equal to find the next one,it is not enough. A5 will result to B7 ,that is not as expected. B5 is expected.
for A3 ,B2-B4 is expected.